# jQuery Ajax Email Validator

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a simple form for a person to fill in their email address. My Ajax script is set to check this address with the database and validate if it exists or not. That step works but I'm stuck on getting the form to submit if the email doesn't exist.

This is my HTML

```html
<form action="user_add.php" method="post" id="addform">
  <input
    type="text"
    class="form-control"
    name="email"
    id="email"
    required
    value=""
  />
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="check()"> Check </a>
</form>
```

This is my JS

```js
function check() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'checkusers.php',
    data: {
      email: $('#email').val()
    },
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
      if (data == true) {
        alert('Please note: A user with this email address already exists.')
        return false
      } else if (data == false) {
        //return true;  --- this doesn't work
        //$('form').submit(); --- this doesn't work
        $('form').trigger('submit') // --- this doesn't work
      }
    },
    error: function (data) {
      //error
    }
  })
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried `$('#addform').submit();`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Yes, I tried that as well but it doesn't work.

Comment: @freedomn-m I'm getting the right response back on the call. It's just not triggering the form submit.

Comment: Ah - thanks for clarifying - you want: `$('form')[0].submit();` - note the *[0]*

Comment: An alternative to `$('form')[0].submit();` should be `$('form:first').submit();`.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware no - that would call the jquery submit, `$(..)[0].submit()` will call the javascript/DOM submit.  They're not the same method and OP is already trying (and failing) with the jquery submit.  `$('form:first')`->jquery object, `$('form')[0]`->DOM node

Comment: @freedomn-m OK, I see, a small but important difference.

Comment: @freedomn-m I've used `$('form')[0].submit();` but now I get `Uncaught TypeError: $(...)[0].submit is not a function` in the console.

Comment: That means your selector does not represent / is not a `<form>`

Comment: @freedomn-m How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to everyone for your input. I had a stray submit button higher up on the page I was working on

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">
```

When I took this out, the following bit worked:

```
$('form').trigger('submit');
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) is probably the best way.

```
function validateEmail(email) {
    const re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
}
function check(){  
  var email = $('#email').val();                  
  if (validateEmail(email)) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "checkusers.php",
        data: {
            'email' : email 
        },
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            if(data == true) {
                alert('Please note: A user with this email address already exists.');
                return false;
            }
            else if(data == false) {
                //return true;  --- this doesn't work
                //$('form').submit(); --- this doesn't work
                $('form').trigger('submit'); // --- this doesn't work
                
            }
        },
        error: function(data){
            //error
        }
    });
  } else {
    // error email not valid
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't address OPs issue and in fact repeats it (`return false` from `success:` does nothing).  OP is not asking how to validate the email format (which is notoriously impossible via regex as easy to find valid email addresses that don't pass).

Comment: Yes, this unfortunately doesn't address my issue. In the console I can see my php/json is returning a false value for "data" as it should but the trigger isn't working.

Comment: Try to add submit button, with display: none and trigger click on this submit button

Comment: @Prashant Can you please elaborate? If the button is hidden, how must I trigger the click if it can't be clicked on?

Comment: It can be triggered, even if it is not visibile on browser